# Different links that use the same link text may be confusing: See matching tag(s)?

Tags: html

I am using html5 and css3 in my site project.

My css

```
.featured-posts{
    display: block; 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 960px;
}


.featured-posts li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.featured-posts li .thumb{
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 0em;

    background: #f1f1f1 url(../img/plus.png) no-repeat center center ;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3); 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3); 
}

.featured-posts li .thumb img{
    margin: 5px;
}

.featured-posts li .thumb span:hover img{
    opacity: 0.4;
}


.featured-posts .link-button{
    opacity: 0;
}

.featured-posts li:hover .link-button{
    opacity: 1;
}

.featured-posts li .link-button:hover{
    background: #f1f1f1;

    padding: 2px 8px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(56, 7, 7, 1); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(56, 7, 7, 1); 
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2); 
}

.featured-posts .excerpt-arrow{
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: 20px;
    background: url(../img/excerpt-arrow.png) no-repeat top left;
}

.featured-posts .excerpt{
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.featured-posts .excerpt .heading {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#content-wrap .featured-posts .excerpt .heading a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #606060;
}

#content-wrap .featured-posts .excerpt .heading a:hover{
    color: #000000;
}
```

my html code-

```
 <ul class="featured-posts">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="thumb" title="An image"><img src="img/Web.png" alt="Post" /></a>
                            <div class="excerpt">
                                <div class="heading"><a href="Web-Designing.html">Web Design</a></div>
                                <p>MCS PMS is a comprehensive Front Desk Reservation/Check-In solution package that is EPABX compliant and integrates well advance with other M Cubic modules like POS &amp; Housekeeping Department.</p><br />
                                <br />
                                <a href="Web-Designing.html">Read More,..</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="thumb" title="An image"><img src="img/Logo.png" alt="Post" /></a>
                            <div class="excerpt">
                                <div class="heading"><a href="Logo-Designing.html">Logo Design</a></div>
                                <p>We provide unbelievable, unique logo-design to brand your representation and identity. We offer several designs.</p><br />
                                <br /><br /><br />
                                <a href="Logo-Designing.html">Read More,..</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="thumb" title="An image"><img src="img/Broucher.png" alt="Post" /></a>
                            <div class="excerpt">
                                <div class="heading"><a href="Brochure-Designing.html">Brochure Design</a></div>
                                <p>We are ready to produce a fantastic piece of printing design, which really reflects the goals and promotional aims of your business.</p><br />
                                <br /><br />
                                <a href="Brochure-Designing.html">Read More,..</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
```

> Different links that use the same link text may be confusing: See
>   matching tag(s) 
>                 on line(s

this Error comes on each read more anchor tag while testing total Validator tool.

what is the mistake in

```
<a href="Logo-Designing.html">Read More,..</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think you've made a mistake. Your code looks correct.
The validator you are using is most likely reporting a "warning" because for accessability reasons the link text being the same could cause confusion to some users.
If you are really concerned with these errors try using

`<a href="Logo-Designing.html">Read More about logo designing..</a>`

instead of

`<a href="Logo-Designing.html">Read More,..</a>`

This will make your button design a challenge but will stop the warnings.

OR

Understand that is is a warning - not an arror.